# JQuery-ui range slider with numbers under handlers not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to do a slider range that shows the quantity under each one of the handlers, I followed a working fiddle that uses  jquery 1.6.2 and jquery-ui 1.8.5, but in my project I use  jquery 2.1.4 and the jquery-ui 1.11.4. It almost works, but there are some issues:

- There is a fixed 0 under the begining of the slider bar.
- The quantity only appears when I move one of the buttons, and it only
  appears under the button I am moving. When I move the other button
  the quantity disapears from the first button and shows in the actual
  button.
- Console shows me a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
  'nodeType' of undefined"

This is my actual range slider with the commented issues: https://jsfiddle.net/zykw73tj/1/

This is the original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/william/RSkpH/1/

I obtained the working fiddle from this previous question: [jQuery UI Slider: move the value along (with) the handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415963/jquery-ui-slider-move-the-value-along-with-the-handle?rq=1)

If I change the JQuery and the JQuery-UI of the original fiddle for the new ones I see the same issues than in mine.

Thanks

```
    -- HTML --
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="min"></div>
<div id="max"></div>


-- JQUERY --
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#slider").slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      step: 10,
      values: [0, 1000],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
          var delay = function() {
              var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).data('index.uiSliderHandle');
              var label = handleIndex == 0 ? '#min' : '#max';
              $(label).html(ui.value + '€').position({
                  my: 'center top',
                  at: 'center bottom',
                  of: ui.handle,
                  offset: "0, 10"
              });
          };

          // wait for the ui.handle to set its position
          setTimeout(delay, 5);
      }
  });

  $('#min').html($('#slider').slider('values', 0) + '€').position({
      my: 'center top',
      at: 'center bottom',
      of: $('#slider a:eq(0)'),
      offset: "0, 10"
  });

  $('#max').html($('#slider').slider('values', 1) + '€').position({
      my: 'center top',
      at: 'center bottom',
      of: $('#slider a:eq(1)'),
      offset: "0, 10"
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things you have to rectify.

1. `var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).data('index.uiSliderHandle');`

   here `handleIndex` is `undefined`. Try `index()` instead of using data
   like `$(ui.handle).index()`
2. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined`
   the above error is caused by the below two lines, since there is no anchor tag present. Instead try span because the handle is shown by using `span` element.

   `of: $(#slider a:eq(0)),`

   `of: $('#slider a:eq(1)'),`

Instead try

`of: $(#slider span:eq(0)),`

`of: $('#slider span:eq(1)'),`

See working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zykw73tj/4/)

Hope this helps...

Comment: yup. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with Jquery Core & UI version.

You can try this

```js
  $(function() {

    $("#slider").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 10,
        values: [0, 500],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var delay = function() {
                var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).data('index.uiSliderHandle');
                
                var label = handleIndex == 0 ? '#min' : '#max';
                
                $(label).html('$' + ui.value).position({
                    my: 'center top',
                    at: 'center bottom',
                    of: ui.handle,
                    offset: "0, 10"
                });
            };
            
            // wait for the ui.handle to set its position
            setTimeout(delay, 5);
        }
    });

    $('#min').html('$' + $('#slider').slider('values', 0)).position({    
        my: 'center top',
        at: 'center bottom',
        of: $('#slider a:eq(0)'),
        offset: "0, 10"
    });
    
    $('#max').html('$' + $('#slider').slider('values', 1)).position({

        my: 'center top',
        at: 'center bottom',
        of: $('#slider a:eq(1)'),
        offset: "0, 10"
    });


  });
```

```css
  #slider 
  {
      width: 80%;
      margin-left: 1em;
  }

  #min, #max {
      width: 50px;
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="min"></div>
<div id="max"></div>
```